# How do you extract data from gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

How do you extract data from gdb so you can examine it in another program?

I am using gdb to debug a program. To see what is in array `udata`, I have created a source file called *printudata* with the following contents:

```
print udata[0]
print udata[1]
print udata[2]
...
print udata[143]
```

From within *gdb* I can execute that using *source* command and get output like this:

```
(gdb) source printudata
$399 = 1
$400 = 2.5
$401 = .3-10
...
$542 = <number>
```

So far, that is the best I can do for examining memory.

The only thing I can think of to do with this is (learn regular expressions and) strip off everything up to the equal sign so I can paste this into a spreadsheet which will tell me whether it's correct.

*Is this the really the best way to get output from gdb?* I am learning all this on my own and only have the basic, free tools that come with Linux (and am a beginner with all the above listed technologies)

Comment: Small hint, use `p udata@143` to print the array from 0 to 143 instead of 143 seperate print statements.

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't get that to work. Maybe because I'm doing C programming and udata is really a pointer to an array rather than an array.

Comment: If so, use `p *udata@143`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print an array if it is really an array like this:

```
p udata
```

But, if `udata` is really a pointer, then you can use a cast to make `gdb` print it like an array.

```
p *(double(*)[144])udata
```

If you really want the line at a time output of your current "script", you can define a function and use a loop:

```
define print_udata
 set $i=0
 while ($i < 144)
  p udata[$i]
  set $i=$i+1
 end
end
```

To log the output to a file, you can enable/disable logging:

```
set logging on
...gdb commands...
set logging off
```

The output will be in a file called `gdb.txt`.

Comment: Logging and my first successful `regexp` (finally!) did the trick nice and simple. But I also very much liked what you showed for printing `udata` when it's really a pointer (in C, I think array names and pointers are the same thing - or at least very similar). That will be very useful. One day when I have more time I will post a question asking someone to explain how that statement works to me.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above, gdb has the "output" and "printf" commands.  These don't enter the value into the value history, and they let you control the output much more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

`gdb` has built-in scripting in both its own scripting language and in python.  You can even script GDB from *within* a python program. You can use any of those options to write the data to a file.

More information about python & gdb [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PythonGdbTutorial).

Comment: Thanks. That will be a useful link to me in the future.